Why does my discord bot display the gif links in ['link_of_gif'] format instead of just the link itself
First, I created a json file where I stored all the links I want the bot to display
{   
    "yup": [
        "https://tenor.com/view/mourinho-jose-mourinho-yes-yes-yes-yes-oh-yes-gif-745895004274181051"
    ] ,

    "calma":[
        "https://tenor.com/view/calma-relax-ronaldo-gif-16922523"
    ] ,

    "respect":[
        "https://tenor.com/view/respect-mou-mourinho-man-manchester-gif-19028709"
    ] ,

    "nospeak":[
        "https://tenor.com/view/josémourinho-big-trouble-if-i-speak-prefer-not-to-speak-interview-gif-16725048"
    ]  ,

    "shush":[
        "https://tenor.com/view/jose-mourinho-ssh-manchester-united-mufc-shush-gif-10178656"
    ],

    "sui":[
        "https://tenor.com/view/sui-siu-ronaldo-football-portugal-gif-25997537"
    ]


}

Now, I open the json file in the main bot file, the keyword will respond to each gif in the json file
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import requests, json

links = json.load(open("gif.json"))

@bot.command(name = "yup", aliases = ["calma", "respect", "nospeak", "shush", "sui"])
async def gif(ctx):
    gif_link = links.get(ctx.invoked_with)
    await ctx.send(gif_link)


I cannot figure out why it's displaying in ['link_of_the_gif'] format
I asked chatgpt and it said to use
links = json.load(open("gif.json", "r"))

it didn't work
I followed a youtube tutorial for this, can someone explain some of the functions and methods used?

as your json file contains lists for every entry i'm going to assume str(list of single link here) will convert to [link] were the [] come from it being a list, you should be able to remove the square brackets in your json or use str(gif_link[0])

Your JSON file maps words to lists of links. See this for example (abbreviated for readability):
{   
    "yup": [
        "..."
    ],
    ...
}

When you access this structure using links.get(ctx.invoked_with), so for example links.get("yup") it will return whatever is stored behind that word.
In this case, it is a list of URLs (denoted with square brackets [...]).
To get a single link you either need to modify the JSON file by removing the square brackets, or the Python script by accessing one item from the list (f.ex. the first one).
Solution: Change the JSON file
{   
    "yup": "https://tenor.com/view/mourinho-jose-mourinho-yes-yes-yes-yes-oh-yes-gif-745895004274181051,
    ...

This stores only a single URL behind the word "yup". It makes retrieval in Python a bit easier, but you are limited to a single item.
Solution 2: Change the Python Scipt
async def gif(ctx):
    gif_link = links.get(ctx.invoked_with)[0]  # <-- "[0]" accesses the first element of the list

This Python code can have a couple of errors (Solution one is also affected by "missing words").
So consider this Python code instead:
async def gif(ctx):
    gif_links= links.get(ctx.invoked_with)
    if not gif_links:
        await ctx.send("No such gif found!")
    await ctx.send(gif_links[0])

Bonus: Randmoize images
Your JSON file (with lists) makes it possible to have more than one image. You can use random.choice() to pick one at random. For example
{   
    "yup": [
        "http://<image-url-1>",
        "http://<image-url-2>",
    ],
    "calma":[
        "http://<image-url-1>",
        "http://<image-url-2>",
    ],
    ...
}

from random import choice

async def gif(ctx):
    gif_links = links.get(ctx.invoked_with)
    if not gif_links:
        await ctx.send("No such gif found!")
    await ctx.send(choice(gif_links))


Hi, thank you for the answer, I understand now. On top of the code, I'm trying to create a way to spam the gifs by typing spam_(name of the trigger word), for example spam_yup, and it will spam the gif a number of times, can you give me some hint or tips on how to do that?

Can you clarify what you mean with the word "spam"? Also, if the the answer solved your problem you should accept it so other people can see that it is a valid solution.
